# How can I safely delete KDE Plasma?

Tags: kde, uninstall, 19.04, plasma, kde-connect

Today, I installed KDE Plasma on my Ubuntu 19.04 laptop to try it out and see how having multiple desktop environments worked. I ran the commands `sudo apt install tasksel` and `sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop` which I found online.

I logged into Ubuntu and selected Plasma as the desktop environment when I was logging in. I tried it for a few minutes, and thought I would keep it alongside GNOME.

However, then I realized that KDE Connect from Plasma was interfering with the functionality of GSConnect in GNOME, so I tried deleting KDE with `sudo tasksel remove kubuntu-desktop`.

While watching the process, I realized that it was deleting a lot of software that it shouldn't have been, including the camera app, IDLE, Firefox, GNOME Tweaks, and even the default Settings app, so I canceled the uninstallation. I've noticed many other strange issues, like the ":" separating hours and minutes on the clock being replaced by a white box, having the Trash and my home folder no longer appear on the desktop, and even not being able to access the internet...could it possibly have deleted Wi-Fi drivers?

Why did this happen, how can I recover lost software, and how can I safely remove the Plasma desktop environment?

Comment: I've never used taskel to install or uninstall stuff. But if you instead use `sudo apt remove kubuntu-desktop` what is suggested?

Comment: What do you see with `apt remove -s kdeconnect`?

Comment: Let me check, one second

Comment: While it maybe possible to salvage the situation, why not backup your data and do a clean install of your original system?

Comment: It said "1 not fully installed or removed" when I ran apt remove -s kdeconnect

Comment: I could do a clean install, but is there a way to recover my lost apps first so they will be in the backup?

Comment: No, applications need to be installed afresh.

Comment: Okay, I guess I will do that. Thank you for your help.